# An unhandled exception of type 'system.indexoutofrangeexception' occurred in system.data.dll in console application

Tags: c#

I could not able to fetch 7th column value from excel it throws an error as "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Additional information: Cannot find column 7.

But iam having values in excel for 7th column, Even I couldn't able to fetch after 7th value. I have attached my excelsheet and coding.

Kindly do the needful.

```
     int j=0;
        private void ImportExcel(string strFilePath)
   {
       if (File.Exists(strFilePath))
       {
           String strExcelConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
       + "Data Source=" + strFilePath + ";"
       + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'";
           connExcel = new OleDbConnection(strExcelConn);
           try
           {
               cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
               //Check if the Sheet Exists
               connExcel.Open();
               DataTable dtExcelSchema;
               //Get the Schema of the WorkBook
               dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
               connExcel.Close();
               //Read Data from Sheet1
               connExcel.Open();
               OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
               string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
               cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
               da.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
               da.Fill(ds);
                DisplayText();//Method
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ImportExcel");
           }
           finally
           {
               cmdExcel.Dispose();
               connExcel.Dispose();
           }
       }
       private void DisplayText()
  {
      BAngle();
      BFAngle();
  }
  private void BAngle()
  {
      int Angle = 0;
      for (int i = j; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
      {
          string sname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][Angle].ToString();
          txt_BSA.Text = sname.ToString();
          txt_BSA.Focus();
       }
  }
  private void BFAngle()
  {
      int Fore = 7;
      for (int i = j; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
      {
          string bname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][Fore].ToString();//It throws an error
          txt_BFA.Text = bname.ToString();
          txt_BFA.Focus();

      }
  }
```

I have attached my excel Sheet in below link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_nzYHWVJJ7KOW5xT3ZsSlczOFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is `j` in the for loop ? Where it is declared? I guess the problem is that

Comment: Where you set the value of `j` ? I guess you are accessing [1-7] instead of [0-6]

Comment: @RichaGarg: I have updated J value , J value is 0

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk : Kindly find open the excel, Iam having value of 7th column.

Comment: Are you getting the same error now?

Comment: s still iam facing same error, J has been declared globally ,

Comment: Use ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count -1 as index starts from 0

Comment: S i have tried , Still same error.

Comment: Does the BAngle working properly? Is your dataset proper?

Comment: yes, BAngle is working correctly                                                         Kindly refer the excel which i have given link, Iam not able to fetch from 7th column values.

Till 6 column values i can get values

Comment: Can you share what is coming in the dataset?

Comment: You have obvious off-by-one bugs in your code, using `<=` in your for() statements is wrong and needs to be `<`.  Having trouble with a 7th column might well be an off-by-one bug as well.  Never that clear where Excel starts indexing, sometimes it is 0 and sometimes it is 1.